# Merge of multiple rows to single row in csv Using Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a `.csv` file which looks like

```
ID, Dept
1,x
1,y
1,z
2,a
2,b
2,c
```

output should be

```
ID, Dept
1, x;y;z
2, a;b;c
```

I tried the with below in the PowerShell but it is returning 0 for both columns

```
$csvValues = Get-Content "DeptDetails.csv"
$duplicates = $csvValues | group-object ID | ? Count -gt 1

$objs = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
ForEach ($duplicate in $duplicates){
$objs.Add([pscustomobject]@{ID = ($duplicate.Group.ID | select -Unique) -as [int];
GroupName=($duplicate.Group.Dept | ? Length -gt 0) -join ';'})
}
$objs | Sort ID
```

Comment: Was a formatting issue. The last entry should be 2,c - shouldn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `Import-Csv` cmdlet to load your `csv`. Group the entries by its `ID` using the `Group-Object` cmdlet. Then you can iterate over the group using the `Foreach-Object` cmdlet and create your desired Object for each `ID`. Finally export it back to csv using the `Export-Csv` cmdlet:

```
Import-Csv 'DeptDetails.csv' | Group-Object ID | ForEach-Object {
    [PsCustomObject]@{
        ID = $_.Name
        Dept = $_.Group.Dept -join ';'
    }
} | Export-Csv 'DeptDetails_output.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: It works. Thanks. Just want to understand what is the significance of .Name and .Group here?

Comment: We group the csv object by its ID, so if you just execute `Import-Csv 'DeptDetails.csv' | Group-Object ID` you will see that the result object array (which we iterate) contains a `Name` and `Group` property where `Name` is the `ID` (because we groupt by it). Please consider accepting the answer.

Comment: How can I use "Get-content" here, if I need to read and write into the same file.